# Why does terminal keep closing right after I open it?

Tags: 14.04, command-line

I tried to edit the profile so that when I start my gnome-terminal it always starts with archey... So after adding archey to something, I closed my terminal and tried to re-open it... However it closed right immediately afterwards...

Comment: What "something" did you add to (`~/.profile`?`~/.bashrc`?) Have you tried opening the file in a text editor and reverting/commenting out your changes?

Comment: I right clicked in the terminal and wrote it in this one space. Can't remember what it was titled though... How do I open the file in a text editor?

Comment: Find the file in the File Manager, right click on the file and select Edit.

Comment: Couldn't find any changes. Maybe there's an alternative terminal with similar features?

Comment: It sounds like you may have modified the `gnome-terminal` profile itself, rather than any profile/resource file for your shell. In 12.04 you could probably undo that using `gconftool` however I'm not sure whether the settings have moved to the dconf database under 14.04. Meantime you could use a plain `xterm`.

Comment: Okay thanks. If you come up with a way to fix my terminal, please tell me how to fix it haha

Comment: Well you could try opening the unity run dialog (Alt+F2) or start an `xterm` from the launcher, then try `gconftool --recursive-unset /apps/gnome-terminal`. **NOTE: this is essentially a 'factory reset' for `gnome-terminal` and for example will may delete any custom profiles that you may have set up**.

Comment: @steeldriver Please, post that as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you may have modified the gnome-terminal profile itself, rather than any profile/resource file for your shell.

At least in 12.04 (and as far as I can tell in 14.04 - although `gconf` functionality seems to be transitioning to the `dconf` database with successive releases), you can essentially reset your `gnome-terminal` preferences to  their factory defaults using the `gconftool` command:

```
gconftool --recursive-unset /apps/gnome-terminal
```

In the absence of acurrently working `gnome-terminal` you will either need to use the desktop run dialog <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, or start an alternative terminal emulator such as a plain `xterm` from the dash, to run the command.